# PyFERRET commands on MacTerminal not working

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, anaconda, ferret

I installed PyFerret through the terminal using Anaconda. Following the instructions from:
https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/blob/master/README.md
Seems like the install was successful since I can activate the environment with

```
conda activate FERRET
```

My command line name changes from **(base)Mac:Directory User$** to **(FERRET)Mac:Directory User$** which I assume indicates that PyFERRET is active.
Then I tried to give a few commands:

```
(FERRET)Mac:Directory User$ FILE CrawfordPoint_surface.nc 
CrawfordPoint_surface.nc: NetCDF Data Format data
```

Then I tried using other commands like PLOT which some can be found at: https://ferret.pmel.noaa.gov/Ferret/documentation/users-guide/commands-reference/PLOT
However, my terminal's response was that those commands were not found.
Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not mean `pyferret` is active, only that the environment is active. You still need to invoke `pyferret` first.

Comment: Oh I see what you mea. I was able to activate it after that, thank you!